# Exclude Reply User Ids in Twitter API

Tags: twitter

i want to exclude some mention users while sending the tweet so i mentioned in the code as exclude_reply_user_ids and passing this parameter to /statuses/update.json. But still i cant exclude users after tweeting reply.

So Here is my code :

```
$params = array(
                'status' => $message,
                'auto_populate_reply_metadata' => 'true',
                'tweet_mode' => 'extended',
                'in_reply_to_status_id' => $status_id,
                'in_reply_to_screen_name' => $screenname,
                'exclude_reply_user_ids' => $exids
            );


    $res = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $config->twitter_api_url . '/statuses/update.json',
                $params,
                true,
                true
            );


[output][1]
[output][2]
[output][3]
[output][4]
[output][5]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfmvs.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUMx2.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfzEL.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XQYr.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3QCy.png
```

Comment: What is the value of $exids? Remember that the documentation states that you cannot omit / remove the @handle of the original poster of the thread.

Comment: 'exclude_reply_user_ids' =>763291950506139648,890517830986211329,745907135041642496 im passing these values in $params and sending to the /statuses/update.json. You can check the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfmvs.png

Comment: Hi Andy, can you provide me a example of 'exclude_reply_user_ids' (parameter) to /statuses/update.json in php.